Prove continuity of the affine extension mapping between geometric simplicial complexes
Let $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ be geometric simplicial complexes. Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be their associated abstract simplicial complexes. Let $f: V(K_1) \to V(K_2)$ be a simplicial mapping.
We define the affine extension $||f||: ||\Delta_1|| \to ||\Delta_2||$ between the polyhedra of the geometric simplicial complexes by extending $f$ affinely to the relative interiors of the simplices of $\Delta_1$, as follows: Let $\sigma=$supp$(x)$ be the support of $x$. This means that $x$ is contained in the relative interior of $\sigma$. Let $v_0,...,v_k$ be the vertices of $\sigma$ and $x=\sum_{i=0}^k \alpha_i v_i$ with $\alpha_0,...,\alpha_k \geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^k \alpha_i = 1$.
We define $||f||(x) = \sum_{i=0}^k \alpha_i f(v_i)$.
This comes from Matousek, Using the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem, section 1.5. I am trying to prove continuity of $||f||$.
It seems very intuitive to me. Though, I have some trouble figuring out a formal proof.
What I already thought of: If we restrict $||f||$ to the relative interior of an arbitrary simplex, then $||f||$ ist just a linear polynomial in multiple variables, if I'm correct. Therefore continuity is given. But if we approach the intersections of two simplices, then a point in that interesection can be written as two different convex combinations with coefficient defined by each single simplex. How do I argue continuity here?
